# Windows Task Scheduler: IAction.QueryInterface() returns an error I cannot find a definition for

Tags: c++, winapi, com, scheduled-tasks

I am attempting to schedule a task (to open an .exe at a specific time) using C++ win32. But at one specific point I am getting an error, I have searched & searched to try & find the definition of this error but I cannot find it?

Do you know what this error means: **Hexadecimal: 80004003  Decimal: 2147500035**

*I wont post the whole function because its rather long (unless you may need it to determine the error context?).*

The code I am using (that causes the error) is the following:

```
//  QI for the executable task pointer.
hr = action -> QueryInterface( IID_IExecAction, (void**) execAction );
action -> Release();

if( FAILED(hr) )
{
    printf("QueryInterface call failed for IExecAction: %x %X %u \n", hr, hr, hr );
    rootFolder -> Release();
    task -> Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return false;
}
```

***The output is: QueryInterface call failed for IExecAction: 80004003 80004003 2147500035***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0x80004003 is an "invalid pointer" error, a.k.a. `E_POINTER`.

I assume the declaration of `execAction` is something like:

```
IExecAction* execAction = NULL;
```

But, QueryInterface expects a pointer to an interface pointer.  In other words, you pass a storage location in which to place an `IUnknown*`... or, in this specific case, a `IExecAction*`.

So, you need to pass the *address* of `execAction` so QueryInterface can return the interface pointer to you.  As in:

```
hr = action -> QueryInterface( IID_IExecAction, (void**) &execAction );
```

I assume this is what's happening since initializing pointer values to NULL is a common coding practice, and [QueryInterface is documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682521(v=vs.85).aspx) to return `E_POINTER` when the second argument is NULL.  If not, please update your question with the declaration of `execAction`.

Comment: This answer would be perfect if you'd show how to break down the `hr` into its components.

Comment: How would that help in this case?  In all the years I've worked with COM, I think I've had to do that maybe twice.

Comment: Thank you :), it worked I can schedule my task now :) This task scheduler stuff in win32 is rather complex, do you know of any tutorials that describe what each IWhateva (ITask, IAction, etc.) does?

Comment: No problem.  If you get an answer on the site that solves your problem, you can click the checkmark next to it to "accept" it.  As for tutorials, a lot of the funkiness comes from COM itself, which is a crazy complex system.  (Your problem is actually a generic problem with COM and not specific to the task scheduler.)  I'd look at a COM tutorial first.  Don't know of any good ones myself, though.  And I know pretty much nothing about the task scheduler API, sorry.

Comment: Dunno if you've tried the MSDN documentation yet: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446802(v=vs.85).aspx -- sometimes the overview sections can be helpful.